# How to generate statically linked executables?

Tags: rust, static-linking

I am trying to create a static executable with Rust. I am *not* trying to statically link a particular library, I am trying to create a executable which *does not use dynamic linking at all*. I have the following (otherwise working) test:

```
$ cat hello.rs
fn main()
    {
    print!("Hello, world!\n");
    }
$ rustc hello.rs -o hello
$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
 dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, [etc]
```

Note the `dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Static executables have `statically linked` instead. (And in my case `corrupted section header size`, although I would be pleasantly astonished if I can convince Rust to replicate *that*.)

What options do I need to pass to `rustc` to get it to generate a actual static executable (for concreteness: one which even `file` agrees is statically linked).

Comment: Perhaps the -C link-args='...' option can help you?

Comment: Note that your question only pertains to Linux - AFAIK, [you cannot statically link executables on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html). I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [using musl instead of glibc wih rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24777)

Comment: This [internals thread](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/static-binary-support-in-rust/2011/10) may also be of interest. It also points towards musl.

Comment: @Shepmaster, yes, you can. It even says so on the page you linked: "building crt0.o for yourself".

Comment: But surely `print` relies on system functionality that requires dynamic linkage?

Comment: @llogiq, rustc doesn't seem to actually respect the options passed that way when they conflict with default options enabling dynamic linking, but thanks.

Comment: @RenatoZannon, thank you, that's actually helpful.

Comment: @Mikhail, I don't know the precise details on other systems, but on linux (and give or take register allocation most other unixes) `print` bottoms out (via either function calls or inlining) to `mov eax,1 ; mov ebx,fdout ; mov ecx bufptr ; mov edx buflen`. It's probably *possible* to design a system call interface that truly requires dynamic linking, but only a raging incompetent would do so for a general purpose OS.

Comment: @DavidX Well, this is how its done on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540478/how-to-write-to-the-console-in-fasm . Looks like the c  style call uses dynamic linking,`'msvcrt.dll'`. It is not clear what `WriteConsole` does.

Comment: @Mikhail, it probably bottoms out to some undocumented interrupt. (As I said, I don't know the precise details.) @DavidX, we forgot the `int 0x80`.

Comment: @DavidX Yeah, thats how DOS did it (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/12/21/creating-a-tiny-hello-world-executable-in-assembly), but I don't think we expect the same thing from a modern OS. For example, you need a pointer the output stream, this might be different for each window?

Comment: @Mikhail, you don't need a pointer the output stream, stdout is identified by the integer one, and it has nothing to do with X11 or any other GUI.

Answer (score 69):

[Since Rust 1.19](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1190-2017-07-20), you can statically link the C runtime (CRT) to avoid this very common situation on Windows:

> The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Add this to your `.cargo/config` file, using the appropriate target triple for your platform:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
```

An alternative to editing `.cargo/config` is to pass `-C target-feature=+crt-static` to rustc by hand.

See also:

- [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1721-crt-static.md)
- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37545)
- [Cargo config documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html)

Comment: This compiler option is now also available for `linux-gnu` targets since 1.48. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1480-2020-11-19

Comment: C Runtime docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html#static-and-dynamic-c-runtimes

Comment: how does one do this when using `cargo build`?

Comment: this seems to cause proc macro dependencies unable to build

Answer (score 67):

Rust statically links everything but glibc (and libgcc, iirc) by default.

If you want to get a 100% statically linked binary, you can use MUSL with 1.1. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24777 is the initial support, we hope to make it much easier to use in the future.

---

**EDIT**: It's distributed via `rustup` now, so you can add `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` as a target : `rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

And then build to this target : `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

Comment: In 2019, is `musl` _still_ the only way to get 100% statically linked binary? Can we get 100% statically linked binary with `glibc` now?

Comment: I don’t believe that glibc really intends to ever support it as a first-class thing, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Hey Steve, checking in in 2021; any updates that make this easier per your "we hope to make it much easier in the future"?

Comment: It's distributed via rustup now, so you can "rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" and then "cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl"

Comment: @SteveKlabnik that should honestly be its own answer! Thanks.