# What is the requirements for running a Rust compiled program on another Windows machine?

Tags: compilation, rust, requirements

I'm totally new to Rust. I installed Rust on my Windows 10 machine. Created a simple helloworld program like this:

```
fn main() {
    print!("Hello world!");
}
```

And compiled it with `rustc rust.rs`. After that there are two files generated:

```
admin@myserver MINGW64 ~/Documents/rust_test
$ ls -latrh
total 1.6M
drwxr-xr-x 1 admin 197121    0 Sep  2 03:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin 197121   45 Sep  4 00:26 rust.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 admin 197121 146K Sep  4 00:26 rust.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin 197121 1.5M Sep  4 00:26 rust.pdb
drwxr-xr-x 1 admin 197121    0 Sep  4 00:26 .
```

I can successfully run `rust.exe` and get the proper result. However, when I copy `rust.exe` to another newly created Windows 2016 virtual machine and run it, I got this error:

[image]

My question is, what's the requirement to run a Rust compiled program on a machine that doesn't have Rust installed? Do I need to install the `vc++ build tools` on it too (just as I did on the development machine)?

Comment: You need to install the [C++ runtime libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) in the correct version (the „140“ indicates the version).

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it works now. This isn't on the documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: @UweKeim, don't answer questions in comments ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) in the correct version.

The "140" in the file name in your error message indicates the version, which should be the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

---

As a shortcut, here are the most common dowload links for other versions:

- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 — [32-bit (x86)](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 — [32-bit (x86)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 — [32-bit (x86)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 — [32-bit (x86)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU3/vcredist_x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU3/vcredist_x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2010 — [32-bit (x86)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/2/4/d242c3fb-da5a-4542-ad66-f9661d0a8d19/vcredist_x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 — [32-bit (x86)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/1/1116b75a-9ec3-481a-a3c8-1777b5381140/vcredist_x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/2/4/d242c3fb-da5a-4542-ad66-f9661d0a8d19/vcredist_x64.exe)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2005 — [32-bit (x86)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/3/4/d342efa6-3266-4157-a2ec-5174867be706/vcredist_x86.exe), [64-bit (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/4/914851c6-9141-443b-bdb4-8bad3a57bea9/vcredist_x64.exe)

Answer (score 7):

You can also statically link the CRT by adding

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static", "-Zunstable-options"]
```

to your `.cargo/config`. As pointed out in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387312/2430485).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but I resolved it by installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2019.  You do not need to stick with 2015.  Any newer version will work just fine.