# Does a user of a rust program on Windows still require to have Visual Studio C++ Build tools installed?

Tags: rust

I plan to develop several programs using Rust programming language which will be deployed on the computer of several colleagues using Windows 10 (64 bits). According to what I understand by reading [the online installation guide](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install), in order to install Rust develoment environment on Windows, the installation of **Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Build tools** is a prerequisite.

My question is: Once a program has been compiled and the executable has been created and deployed on the computer of my colleagues, do they also need to have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Build tools installed on their computers in order to be able to use these programs or this is just a prerequisite for develoment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build tools should not be necessary on the target machine, but that machine *probably* needs the *redistributable C++ runtime* unless you force statically linking the CRT.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387312/8182118
- [What is the requirements for running a Rust compiled program on another Windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52153676/8182118)