# How can I create a static executable with rustc using glibc instead of musl?

Tags: rust, runtime, static-linking, libc

I wrote simple code in C, Go and Rust.

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

foo.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello");
}
```

foo.rs

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}
```

Then I built them all.

```
$ gcc -static -o cfoo foo.c
$ go build -o gofoo foo.go
$ rustc -o rustfoo foo.rs
```

They run fine.

```
$ ./cfoo; ./gofoo; ./rustfoo
hello
hello
hello
```

The binary of Rust executable was too small compared to the other two, so I suspected that it is not a static executable.

```
$ ls -l cfoo gofoo rustfoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lone lone  755744 Oct 23 21:17 cfoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lone lone 1906945 Oct 23 21:17 gofoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lone lone  253528 Oct 23 21:17 rustfoo
```

I confirmed that Rust does not produce a static executable.

```
$ ldd cfoo gofoo rustfoo
cfoo:
    not a dynamic executable
gofoo:
    not a dynamic executable
rustfoo:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe6dfb7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd8d9b75000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd8d9b6b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd8d9b4a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd8d9b30000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd8d996f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd8d9bbb000)
```

Is there any way to produce a static executable for Rust?

I checked other similar answers and they talk about using musl. Is there no way to produce a static executable with glibc? If I must use an alternate way, can you provide a step by step with commands to produce a static executable with `rustc`?

Comment: Did you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387312/4498831

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios That answer is meant for Windows.

Comment: See also [Static linking libc, possible or not, recommended or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/505868/74536) and [Even statically linked programs need some shared libraries which is not acceptable for me. What can I do?](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#Even_statically_linked_programs_need_some_shared_libraries_which_is_not_acceptable_for_me.__What_can_I_do.3F)

Comment: Do you have a static version of glibc on your system?

Comment: @Shepmaster How can I check if static version of glibc is available on my system? `apt-cache search glibc | grep static` turns up no results. But there is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a` on my system. Also, as explained in my question above `gcc -static -o cfoo foo.c` produces a static binary. So I am guessing static glibc is present on my system. Am I right?

Answer (score 20):

It seems things may have changed since this was originally answered.

First, you need to make sure you have a statically linked glibc available on your system. I'm using a RHEL system, so I did that with:

```
sudo yum install glibc-static
```

I believe the Ubuntu / Debian equivalent is:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

After that, you pass the option `-C target-feature=+crt-static` to rustc when compiling your program:

```
$ rustc -o rustfoo -C target-feature=+crt-static main.rs
$ ldd rustfoo
        not a dynamic executable
```

Of course few people run rustc by hand. You can instruct cargo to pass this option to rustc using the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable, like this:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+crt-static" cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

The reason you have to add the `--target` option, even if you are building for the host platform, is that if you don't then the options supplied via `RUSTFLAGS` will be applied when building compile time code such as proc macros, etc which may cause those to fail to compile. If you explicitly specify a target platform then the `RUSTFLAGS` are only applied when compiling code for the target platform. See also [this bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78210).

If you want it to always build statically like this, without needing an environment variable, then you can create a file `.cargo/config.toml` within your project top directory, and put the following content into it:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
target = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

References:

- [cargo configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html)
- [rustc cli options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html)

Comment: Awesome! Currently it has a trouble with proc-macro crates. Workaround is to always specify target `RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+crt-static" cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release`. More on that in issue on github: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78210

Comment: Good catch @michalhosna. I have updated the answer to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile for MUSL, otherwise Rust will depend on your libc.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/musl-support-for-fully-static-binaries.html