# Rust Linux version glibc not found - compile for different glibc / libc6 version

Tags: linux, docker, rust

I compile a Rust binary on one Linux system and try to run it on another. When I run the program I get:

```
./hello-rust: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./hello-rust)
```

GLIBC aka libc6 is installed on the system, however, the version is 2.31 Is there a way to compile the program for a less recent version of libc6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57497 - there's no way to tell the Rust compiler to link a different library other than the one installed on the system.

This means I have to compile the binary on a system that has a less recent version of libc6 installed - then the binary should be compatible with the same version of libc6, or a more recent version*

The most convenient way of doing that would by using a Docker image that has the target libc6 version and rustup.

For myself, the official [Rust docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) had the correct version I could use to compile for my target.

In the working directory:

```
sudo docker pull rust
sudo docker run --rm --user "$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp rust cargo build --release
```

If the official image, which is based on Debian does not satisfy the version requirement, you will have to create a custom docker image, i.e.:

- fork the official [Rust docker image](https://github.com/rust-lang/docker-rust) and set it to use an older version of Debian
- or create an image that is based on an older Debian or other Linux distro image and configure it to install rustup

* I could use a binary compiled with libc6 2.31 on a system that has libc6 2.32 - I'm not sure how far backwards compatibility goes.

Comment: You could also [statically link to glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616507/1411457)

Comment: Add `:z` to the end of the volume mount argument if you are getting permission denied errors (selinux)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way of doing it, try the [cross project](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross). It requires Docker, but is super easy.

```
cargo install cross --git https://github.com/cross-rs/cross
```

Make sure your user can run Docker:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

Then, for example, if you want to compile for **armv6l** arch:

```
cross build --target arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --release
```

If you want to compile for **armv7l**:

```
cross build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --release
```

The compiled file will be placed in the usual target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/... folder.

Make sure to check the proper destination arch in the targeted system with the command arch. Example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arch
armv6l
```