# Pin Rust version for a specific server

Tags: rust

I did a rust binary, which I compile in a ci with the rust docker image, tag rust:buster,
as my server was ubuntu 18.04
Lastly, I could not start the binary on the server anymore after the last compilation.
The error was :

`` /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/xxx/.bin/ctprods) ``

Then I upgraded my server to ubuntu 21.10. The binary worked.

I want to fix the rust version in the ci.

Why did it stop working ?

How do I find the rust version for my server ?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? Did not compile? Crash? Do you have an error message maybe?

Comment: I couldn't run the binary. The error message was :  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/cyprien/.bin/ctprods)

Comment: It does not have much to do with the compiler version, but with how the executable was linked in the host machine. With the most commonly used Linux toolchain (`x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`), it is linked against the platform's glibc. See also [how to generate statically linked executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770604/how-to-generate-statically-linked-executables).