# GLIBC incompatibility on debian docker

Tags: docker, rust, glibc

I'm trying to build a rust app with rust-rocksdb as a dependency.

Using the latest rust docker image to compile and then moving the binary to a debian.
This is how my Dockerfile looks

```
FROM rust:1.61 as builder

RUN USER=root cargo new --bin fbrust
WORKDIR ./fbrust
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml
COPY ./Cargo.lock ./Cargo.lock

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates tzdata libclang-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

ADD . ./

RUN rm ./target/release/deps/fbrust*
RUN cargo build --release


FROM debian:buster-slim
ARG APP=/usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5005

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC \
APP_USER=appuser

RUN groupadd $APP_USER \
    && useradd -g $APP_USER $APP_USER \
    && mkdir -p ${APP}

COPY --from=builder /fbrust/target/release/fbrust ${APP}/fbrust

RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER ${APP}

USER $APP_USER
WORKDIR ${APP}

CMD ["./fbrust"]
```

I'm now getting this error(s):

```
./fbrust: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./fbrust)
./fbrust: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by ./fbrust)
./fbrust: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./fbrust)
```

First of all, I'm confused why do I see both 2.29 and 2.30 required.

I checked within the container and indeed I have 2.28

```
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libc-bin       2.28-10      amd64        GNU C Library: Binaries
```

Is there any other image I can use to achieve compatibility or can I get a hint on what dependencies/setup should I try?

Comment: Debian "Buster" is currently [one release behind](https://www.debian.org/releases/); does changing your runtime image to `debian:bullseye-slim` help?

Comment: Yeah, I just found this link https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libc6 and I realised I need the next one. If you post this as an answer I'll mark as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the list of [Debian releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/), as of this writing Debian 10 "Buster" is one release behind, and Debian 11 "Bullseye" is the current released stable version.  You can also look at the [libc6 package listing](https://packages.debian.org/libc6) and see that "Buster" contains libc6 2.28, and "Bullseye" contains libc6 2.31 (both with local patches).

So for your setup, it should work to change the final image to a newer version of Debian, like

```bash
FROM debian:bullseye-stable # one newer than buster
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust builds binaries for the host system by default; This includes the version of glibc of whatever system compiled the binary. The easiest fix is to **compile the binary in another docker image using the same version of the same distro**.

You should *not* attempt to fix this by changing distro version to match your binary; You binary will again stop working whenever you upgrage/change the distro on your personal computer (or whatever computer you're using to build the binary).

Alternatively, you can try to compile a static binary: ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770604/how-to-generate-statically-linked-executables))

```bash
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```