# Rust include DLL in release

Tags: rust, dll, rust-cargo, libtorch

Im in windows, trying to build a release of a project that uses rust's torch crate.
To install it, I simply added to Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
tch = "0.4.0"
```

If I do cargo run, it goes ok. But if I execute the produced .exe, I get these errors:

```
torch_cu.dll not found
c10.dll not found
```

I tried downloading a compiled version of libtorch and including everything from its /lib/ to the same folder, now with the error:

```
procedure entry point not found
```

I tried statically linking everything by adding a .cargo/config.toml to my project, with the contents:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
```

as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387312/10480432), but nothing changed.

I wasnt able to understand what the tch's [readme](https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs#static-linking) said about it either.

How do I work with these sort of issues?
Thanks for any help! Im new to working on these sort of linking errors...

The sandbox-project I was trying these solutions: https://github.com/titoco3000/torch_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue as I was... I think the version of libtorch that the tch-rs crate uses is not the latest, because just copy-pasting all dlls from libtorch/lib to the same folder didnt work; *but* copying all dlls that were placed by rust at

`\target\debug\build\torch-sys-cba3ef2adb59743a\out\libtorch\libtorch\lib\`

to

`\target\debug\`

does the work! It seens like an terrible solution, but at least works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs, you can link pytorch statically by exporting `LIBTORCH_STATIC=1` environment variable before compilation. Full docs [here](https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs#static-linking).

As for `target-feature=+crt-static`, it affects only C Runtime (`crt` is abbreviation from it) so it would just link Visual C++ Runtime into your application and wouldn't affect other DLLs. Since PyTorch is not a part of C Runtime, it wouldn't affect it any way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but It didnt work... I still get the same error