# Hello world does work in PE but not in PE64

Tags: printf, 64-bit, fasm

I'm trying to kind of write my own x64 Hello world program in FASM on Windows
I tried to rewrite this version: [How to write to the console in fasm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540478/how-to-write-to-the-console-in-fasm), to a x64 program like this:

```
format PE64

entry start

include 'win64a.inc'

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    push hello
    call [printf]
    pop rcx

    push 0
    call [ExitProcess]

section '.rdata' data readable
    hello db 'Hello world!', 10, 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
    library kernel,'KERNEL32.DLL', \
        msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
    import kernel, ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
    import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```

Now the problem is that this compiles fine, but when it is executed it doesn't print anything to the console.

Why does this not work, is `printf` of `msvcrt` silently incompatible with x64?
Have I overseen something?

Can someone tell me how to rewrite this for it to actually print "Hello world!"?

Comment: Parameters (the first 4 anyway) are not passed through the stack like that in the WIN64 calling conventions

Comment: I edited the question. How can I rewrite the program, should I pass 4 dummies or something?

Comment: The first param goes in `rcx`, no push/pop should be necessary here

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work.